# JSON Object to POJO in J2ME

Tags: android, json, java-me, lwuit, nokia-s40

I'm supposed to port an Android app into Nokia S40 app. I used [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) in Android to parse JSON. But unfortunately GSON is not compatible with J2ME. I tried [Flexson](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexjson/files/) and [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) but no luck. So is there any library available to Serialize/Deserialize JSON for J2ME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official [JSON](http://www.json.org/) site points to https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/ Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm using it atm. It only converts JSON string into JSONObject, theres no support for serializing/deserializing objects as GSON and other libraries offer. But, I din't find any. So Using json.me I wrote custom parser to convert JSON string into my POJOs.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you try [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) which has a builtin JSON parser and works well for J2ME, Android, RIM,iOS and Windows.